# Fabric js : Is there any way to define margins inside the canvas?

Tags: canvas, fabricjs

Can we define margins inside canvas, so that object positioning must occur within that margin box? Any object or part of an object which goes out of that defined margin should be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

The feature you're looking for is `clipPath`. By assigning a clipPath to your canvas, only objects within that clipPath will be visible.

```
var clipPath = new fabric.Rect({ width: 100, height: 100, top: 50, left: 50 });
```

See http://fabricjs.com/clippath-part3

Answer (score 0):

I made it this way on React

1. define the margin
   `const [paperMargins, setPaperMargins] =useState({ name:"none", mt : 0, mb: 0, ml:0, mr:0 })`
2. Bind those events

```js
 canvas.current.on( "object:scaling", scalingObject, false );
 canvas.current.on( "object:moving", movingRotatingWithinBounds, false );
 canvas.current.on( "object:rotated", movingRotatingWithinBounds , false);
```

3. Define the functions

   ```js
   const scalingObject = (e) => {
       let shape = e.target;
       let maxWidth = shape.canvas.width - paperMargins.mr;
       let maxHeight = shape.canvas.height - paperMargins.mb;
       //left border
       if(shape.left < paperMargins.ml) {
         shape.left = scalingProperties.left;
         shape.scaleX = scalingProperties.scaleX
       } else {
         scalingProperties.left = shape.left;
         scalingProperties.scaleX = shape.scaleX;
       }
       //right border
       if((scalingProperties.scaleX * shape.width) + shape.left >= maxWidth) {
       shape.scaleX = (maxWidth - scalingProperties.left) / shape.width;
       } else {
       scalingProperties.scaleX = shape.scaleX;
       }
       //top border
       if(shape.top < paperMargins.mt) {
        shape.top = scalingProperties.top;
        shape.scaleY = scalingProperties.scaleY;
        } else {
         scalingProperties.top = shape.top;
        scalingProperties.scaleY = shape.scaleY;
      }
      //bottom border
       if((scalingProperties.scaleY * shape.height) + shape.top >= maxHeight) {
         shape.scaleY = (maxHeight - scalingProperties.top) / shape.height;
       } else {
        scalingProperties.scaleY = shape.scaleY;
       }
     }
   ```

   ```js
    const movingRotatingWithinBounds = (e) => {

      const obj = e.target;
      // if object is too big ignore
      if(obj.height > obj.canvas.height || obj.width > obj.canvas.width){
        return;
      }
      obj.setCoords();
      // top-left  corner
      if(obj.getBoundingRect().top < paperMargins.mt || obj.getBoundingRect().left < paperMargins.ml){
        obj.top = Math.max(obj.top, obj.top-obj.getBoundingRect().top + paperMargins.mt);
        obj.left = Math.max(obj.left, obj.left-obj.getBoundingRect().left + paperMargins.ml);
      }
      // bot-right corner
      let marginB = obj.canvas.height - paperMargins.mb
      let marginR= obj.canvas.width - paperMargins.mr
      if(obj.getBoundingRect().top+obj.getBoundingRect().height  > marginB ||
      obj.getBoundingRect().left+obj.getBoundingRect().width  > marginR){
        obj.top = Math.min(obj.top,
          marginB-obj.getBoundingRect().height+obj.top-obj.getBoundingRect().top);
        obj.left = Math.min(obj.left,
          marginR-obj.getBoundingRect().width+obj.left-obj.getBoundingRect().left);
      }
    }
   ```

```
if you want to change the margin just change the paperMargins
```